# Laravel route not working due to file name

Tags: php, laravel, web-applications, laravel-5.4, php-7

I have been encountering a weird problem with Laravel over the last week.

Basically, lets say for example that I am editing a view, "view.blade.php", and the controller, "ViewController.php", and I am constantly refreshing the browser page to see my changes.

My view is loaded by the index() function of my ViewController like so:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('view');
}
```

Everything is working and I am seeing my changes reflected in the browser. However, all of a sudden for some reason, the page goes white and my view stops loading. No error in Laravel.log or console, nothing. It just shows a white page.

The thing is, if I change the name of my view file to "view2.blade.php" and change my index function to return 'view2' instead, the page loads as normal and works perfectly. It seems that the file name is the only thing keeping the page from loading.

I have tried clearing all the caches with the following artisan commands:

```
php artisan route:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

and executing `php artisan optimize`

However, the problem still persists. I have not modified or added any vendor files.

This doesn't happen too often but it is annoying and it normally "magically" solves itself when I leave it alone for a while to work on another view/controller. However, I just want to know if anyone else has this problem and if there is a solution anywhere.

I defined my route like so:
`Route::resource('view', 'ViewController');`

Using Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0):

try to clear browser cash `ctrl + F5`

Comment: Forgot to include that I tried that too. Also tested in IE and Chrome and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this url `http://yoursite.dev/view/`, do note you need to replace the yoursite.dev with your local domain.

By including the 'view' string in the resource function you are making a restful resource relative to the `/view` base domain.

Here is a link to the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

reference the table `Actions Handled By Resource Controller` for a thorough explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately (but also thankfully lol), the error has already magically fixed itself again (literally did nothing except move on to editing another view, did not edit any files except the new view file and new view controller). However, I did try going straight to the url while it was broken and it still displayed a white page, no errors.

Comment: Do note that in your `resources/views/` directory you need to have a file name `view.blade.php` if you are going to use the function invocation `view('view');`. I'm sure you know this, just throwing it in just in case :) you never know, we all over look things (thumbsup)

Comment: Yah, I have that :). Don't worry, I understand, the most annoying mistakes are definitely the ones with a simple solution that just flies over our heads because we think of everything except some like checking the name or something haha

Comment: Was also hoping this was something simple and I am just being dumb. However, I don't see why changing the file name is enough to make it work all of a sudden. I am also new to web development though, trying my best to grasp everything as quick as possible for work.